# MeteorJS - DDP documentation

Tags: meteor, ddp

The [DDP Documentation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/livedata/DDP.md#ddp-specification) is "a rough description of the protocol and not intended to be entirely definitive."

Does there exist a precise, definitive description of the protocol? If so, where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official specification yet because Meteor has not reached 1.0, and being subject to change, it's not fixed. However, I know that people have written their own DDP clients in other languages. What you found is the most complete documentation so far (and yet it's still quite hidden.)

You may refer to the DDP card on the Meteor Trello for updates on the spec.

> https://trello.com/card/official-ddp-specification/508721606e02bb9d570016ae/53